# DOM - Replace node with an array of nodes (efficiently)

Tags: javascript, dom

What would be an efficient way to replace a DOM node with an array of nodes
(which are a simple array of detached nodes and not HTMLCollection)

(please no jQuery answers)

### [Demo page](http://jsbin.com/wukenejeki/edit?html,js,output)

## HTML

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
  </header>
</body>
```

## JS

```
// generate simple dummy array of detached DOM nodes

var link1 = document.createElement('a');
link1.innerHTML = 'xxx';

var link2 = document.createElement('a');
link2.innerHTML = 'yyy';

var nodesArr = [link1, link2];


// get the element to replace at some place in the DOM.
// in the case, the second <div> inside the <header> element
var nodeToReplace = document.querySelectorAll('header > div')[1];


// replace "nodeToReplace" with "nodesArr"
for(let node of nodesArr)
  nodeToReplace.parentNode.insertBefore(node, nodeToReplace);
nodeToReplace.parentNode.removeChild(nodeToReplace);
```

Comment: Did you find a way that works but you consider inefficient?

Comment: Would simply iterating over the array not be a passable solution?

Comment: Why do you emphasise "*and not HTMLCollection*"? Would there be anything different?

Comment: @Bergi - just to making sure it's a real Array and not another else, such as an HTMLCollection. also, I know of ways ofc, such as iteration, but I'm trying to find a sleek way maybe with some esoteric DOM method or some clever way.

Comment: @DBS - iterating the array would be the most straight-forward approach but will result in quite a lot of code, and i'm trying to find a better approach than that, if exists. seems like the DOM API should have had a solution for such scenario.

Comment: @DBS - I did it with an iteration but I thought there might be a better way, see my updated question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instead of the array:

```
var nodesFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
nodesFragment.appendChild(link1);
nodesFragment.appendChild(link2);

nodeToReplace.replaceWith(nodesFragment); // experimental, no good browser support
nodeToReplace.parentNode.replaceChild(nodesFragment, nodeToReplace); // standard
```

However, just inserting multiple elements in a loop shouldn't be much different with regard to performance. Building a document fragment from an existing array might even be slower.

Comment: @Andreas Ah, indeed. [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) seems to have the same limited support as `replaceWith`

Comment: When approached this question I initially thought about using DocumentFragment which is classical for that, but for some reason it didn't work. let me check it again..

Comment: Note for people reading this in 2021 and beyond: support for `replaceWith` is [fairly good, if not great](https://caniuse.com/?search=replacewith) with modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

My initial solution was a straightforward iteration:

```
// iterate on the Array and insert each element before the one to be removed
for(let node of nodesArr)
  nodeToReplace.parentNode.insertBefore(node, nodeToReplace);
// remove the chosen element
nodeToReplace.parentNode.removeChild(nodeToReplace);
```